# How to use node on https on non-standard ports?

Tags: node.js, ssl

Hi,

I am on a shared hosting and set up my node server like this:

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const fs = require("fs");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

so I can access it from here http://example.net:3000. However, I want to access it from https as well but when I do that I get this error:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to example.net:3000. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

I do have SSL on my server by lets encrypt because I can access my regular site like this https://example.net and it works so tried by changing this `require("http").createServer(app);` to `require("https").createServer(app);` but it still wont work. What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Just swapping "http" to "https" only changes the protocol, but you didn't tell it which certificate to actually use. See the [official Node.js tutorial on setting up an HTTPS server](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) for what's left to do on your side.

Comment: can I do that on a shared hosting? How do I use the certificates I already have?

Comment: That depends entirely on your host, but in 2021 I would certainly hope so.

Comment: But I already have a SSL certificate by lets encrypt which I use on my 80 and 443 ports. Wont this overwrite or interfere in any way with that?

Comment: Why would port 3000 traffic interfere with port 443 traffic? You can run tens of thousands of different servers, all speaking different protocols with different negotiation settings, as long as they all use a different port. That only thing to check when it comes to shared hosting is "do you even get your own pots" because often you don't, and you'll be told to use a VPS instead.

Comment: Yes, I have port 3000 open and in use. My app opens just fine on http://example.net:3000

Comment: Okay so now I did exactly as the tutorial says and I get this new error: `example.net.net:3000 uses an invalid security certificate.
 
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.`

Comment: Never mind, I finally managed to come around it and now its working. Thank you for your help.